# How do I find worst-case complexity of the following code?

Tags: java, algorithm, complexity-theory

Need to know the worst-case complexity of the following code, would be grateful if you could provide the steps of how to solve it. I was thinking of the answer n^3logn, but not sure.

```
int complexity(int n)
  int i,j,c
  for(i=1; i < n; i=i*3)
    for(j=n; j < n*n; j++)
      c++
  for(i=c; i > 0; i--)
    if(random(0...999) > 0)
      for(j=0; j < 3*n; j++)
        c++
    else
      for(j=2*n*n; j > 0; j--)
        c++
  return c
```

Comment: What specifically are you confused about? You can get a much more useful answer if you show how far you have got, and what prevents you from moving further.

Comment: The question is - how big is an `int`? On many languages and architectures, it is limited to 2^32-1 or 2^64-1, which means that the complexity becomes O(1) since `n` cannot go to infinity. That's why complexity is mostly discussed about algorithms that aren't expressed in concrete programming languages. If `n` could have as many bits as there is memory in the machine (like when it's using a `BigInteger`) complexity analysis could make sense. If `n` is a 32-bit integer, we can't have more than `(2^32-1)^2 * 2` iterations in this method no matter what the value of `n`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at the first nested loop

```
for(i=1; i < n; i=i*3)
    for(j=n; j < n*n; j++)
        c++
```

The outer loop runs `log(n)` times [log base 3, but base changes is multiplying by a constant which does not effect the asymptotic complexity] and the inner loop `n^2` times, thus after this loop `c = n^2 * log(n)`.

For the second loop:

```
for(i=c; i > 0; i--)
    if(random(0...999) > 0)
       for(j=0; j < 3*n; j++)
          c++
   else
      for(j=2*n*n; j > 0; j--)
        c++
```

In the worst case the `else` case always happens, so we can modify it to

```
for(i=c; i > 0; i--)
  for(j=2*n*n; j > 0; j--)
    c++
```

The outer loop happens `c` times, which is `O(n^2 * log(n))` and the inner loop increments `c` by `2*n^2`, so `c`  is incremented by `2 * n^2 * n^2 * log(n)`, adding the initial value we get that `c` (and thus the overall complexity) is in `O(2*n^4*log(n) + n^2 * log(n)) = O(n^4 * log(n))`

Answer (score 2):

I hope I'm not just doing your homework for you. In future I recommend showing your thought processes thus far, rather than just your final answer.

Let's look at this code one section at a time.

```
int complexity(int n)
    int i,j,c
    for(i=1; i < n; i=i*3)
        for(j=n; j < n*n; j++)
            c++
```

So in the outer loop, i goes from 1 to n, but each time i is tripled. This means it will finish after log_3(n) loops. Changing base of log is just a constant factor, which doesn't matter in computational complexity, so we can just say log(n).

The inner loop has j going from n to n^2. O(n^2 - n) = O(n^2) since lower powers are dwarfed by higher ones (i.e. quadratic dwarfs linear).

So putting this all together, the first section has computational complexity O(n^2 logn). Now let's look at the second section.

```
for(i=c; i > 0; i--)
    if(random(0...999) > 0)
        for(j=0; j < 3*n; j++)
            c++
    else
        for(j=2*n*n; j > 0; j--)
            c++
return c
```

Now because the outer loop's initialization depends on c, we need to know what c is. c was incremented every time in the first two nested loops, so c's value is proportional to n^2 logn. Thus the outer loop will run O(n^2 logn) times.

For the inner loops, remember we are always considering the worst-case scenario. So the random number generator is a bit misleading: compute the computational complexity of both j loops, and assume the worst case always happens.

The first j loop goes from 0 to 3n, which is simply O(n). The second j loop goes from 2n^2 to 0 which is simply O(n^2). Since the second case is worse, we assume it always happens (even though this is highly improbable). So the inner loop is O(n^2).

Multiplying the two nested loops together, we get O(n^2 logn x n^2) = O(n^4 logn).

Finally, remember we have to see which of the two sections dominated. The first section was O(n^2 logn) and the second was O(n^4 logn), so we want O(n^2 logn + n^4 logn). The latter term obviously dominates, so the final answer is O(n^4 logn).

Hope this helps. Please ask if some part was unclear.

p.s. The current top answer states that c will be ~n^3/3. Because i is tripling every time, this is incorrect; it will be n^2 log_3(n). Otherwise their work is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve this is to work out a *formula* that gives `c` as a function of `n`.  (We can use the number of `c++` operations as a proxy for the overall number of operations.)

In this case, the `random` function means that you can't get an exact formula.  But you can work out two formulae, one for the case where `random` always returns zero, and the other for the case where `random` always returns > zero.

How do you work out the formula / formulae?  Maths!

Hint: the worst-case will be one of the two cases that I mentioned above.  (Which one?  The one whose complexity is worst, of course!)